# Simultaneous transmission of a D2D user

Tags: transceiver

Can a D2D user (a device) transmit simultaneous different signals to a cellular user and a D2D receiver. If we suppose that the D2D device is equipped with SDR technology and can change their frequency channel while transmitting to a cellular user. Moreover will the power factors and timeslots with which it is transmitting will be different in this case.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A single radio, software-defined or not, can't transmit multiple signals at any time. You can interleave transmissions (by packet, TDM, ...) but you can't have them simultaneously. You'd need a second radio.